# Publish docs via GitHub Pages failed

Tags: github, mkdocs

Today I want to add a new page to my Github page. My repo worked well before. But when I add a new directory `lsy/README.md` to `docs`. Error shows.  It just says `Error reading page 'lsy/README.md': no such group`. I cannot understand why. I added some config to `mkdocs.yml`. In fact, even I don't add the config to `mkdocs.yml`, the error shows the same. Any help?

The action log is [here](https://github.com/liusy58/LearningCS/runs/6283584439?check_suite_focus=true)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mkdocs-exlclude` [plugin](https://github.com/apenwarr/mkdocs-exclude) and setup the configuration inside the mkdocs.yml file as:

```
plugins:
  - exclude:
      glob:
        - lsy/README.md
```

Comment: Thank you. So could you please tell me what causes this error?